# How ResetPasswordController works with password_reset table Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

The built-in controller for resetting the password Auth \ Reset Password Controller has the reset function

```
public function reset(Request $request)
{
$request->validate($this->rules(), $this->validationErrorMessages());

// Here we will attempt to reset the user's password. If it is successful we
// will update the password on an actual user model and persist it to the
// database. Otherwise we will parse the error and return the response.
$response = $this->broker()->reset(
    $this->credentials($request), function ($user, $password) {
        $this->resetPassword($user, $password);
    }
);

// If the password was successfully reset, we will redirect the user back to
// the application's home authenticated view. If there is an error we can
// redirect them back to where they came from with their error message.
return $response == Password::PASSWORD_RESET
            ? $this->sendResetResponse($request, $response)
            : $this->sendResetFailedResponse($request, $response);
}
```

Well, here we are working with the user and their incoming data. However, I can't understand where the work with the password_resets table (built-in) is going? After all, after password recovery, entries are added/deleted there. I think (maybe incorrectly) that this is implemented in the broker () method, but I can't find it in the hierarchy of traits, interfaces, and other classes.

Comment: Check out `\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker.php` All the logic is abstracted to use configurations and models etc that are set up for your specific app and users but thats where all the magic happens.

Comment: That said, this sounds like an X Y problem. Why do you want to understand this mechanism, is there something specific you're trying to accomplish? If so, perhaps it would be better to ask about that.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/PasswordBroker.php`

Comment: @WesleySmith Thanks for your reply. Why do I want to know? Just interest, since I feel like I'm using some kind of black box. Yes, in class vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/PasswordBroker.php there are indeed sendResetLink() and reset () methods. These methods have the following lines: method sendResetLink () -- > $this->tokens - >create($user) and method reset () -- > $this->tokens->delete($user); however, I have not found where the create($users) and delete($user) methods are implemented. it maybe work going on with models.

Comment: Gotcha, added an answer based on that, hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout [/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/DatabaseTokenRepository.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/DatabaseTokenRepository.php)

This is the default class that implements the `TokenRepositoryInterface` and is used by the `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/PasswordBroker.php`.

Inside this class you can find all the actual functionality that handles the password resets including the table operations you mention. For example, one method you'll find is:

```
/**
 * Create a new token record.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword  $user
 * @return string
 */
public function create(CanResetPasswordContract $user)
{
    $email = $user->getEmailForPasswordReset();

    $this->deleteExisting($user);

    // We will create a new, random token for the user so that we can e-mail them
    // a safe link to the password reset form. Then we will insert a record in
    // the database so that we can verify the token within the actual reset.
    $token = $this->createNewToken();

    $this->getTable()->insert($this->getPayload($email, $token));

    return $token;
}
```